# How to retrieve array values in codeigniter view?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am having a problem in accessing  a foreach statement when using a multidimensional array.

I can´t show the values ​​separately.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [receita] => 1254
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [receita] => 12
        )

)
```

My code

```
if(!empty($result))
        {
          foreach($result as $result=>$k){
          echo $k->receita;
          }
```

Comment: Where do you see `despesas` anywhere in the `print_r` output?

Comment: Sorry is receita. I´ll change that.

Comment: So where is the problem them? That they are on the same line?

Comment: I´d like acess ​​separately this values.

Comment: Show me two values same time.

Comment: You mean: `$result[0]->receita` ?

Comment: Thats it! 
I will try this. But did not work.